# get dates in array from query result in php

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5

I have got a query result like below using postgresql and laravel 5.3

```
from_date       to_date
26/12/2017      28/12/2017
27/12/2017      31/12/2017
```

I need to get all the dates between 26/12/2017 and 31/12/2017

Pls help

Comment: Based on your limited result set of two records, you are already doing this.  Please show us the source data and your query.

Comment: Query used :                                                                          select from_date , to_date from "tbl_name" 
where  "to_date" >= '2017-12-28'

Comment: Do you want all records where the to and from date lie completely within the range, or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly.. I want all the dates which comes in the range between from date and to date in a single array

Comment: So you want every record between 26/12/2017 and 31/12/2017?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the laravel-5 tag, I suggest using the Laravel Query Builder, which supports doing something like:

```
DB::table('tbl_name')->select('*')->whereDate('from_date','>=','2017-12-26')->whereDate('to_date','<=','2017-12-31')->get();
```

Laravel can be configurd to work with postgresql by default.
If you don't like to use Laravel Query builder, the following raw query should work:

```
select * from "tbl_name" where "to_date" <= '2017-12-26' AND "from_date" >= '2017-12-31'
```